# Why is my kinetic js collision / intersection alg. so slow

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, collision, intersection

Sorry for my bad English!

I have 2 questions about Kinetic JS and Intersections.

1. As you can see in my code example, the Intersection method is extremely slow even at only 10 nodes. Why is that?

   http://jsfiddle.net/Maj0rrush/YWGzE/8/
2. On an intersection I need to destroy both nodes but line 84 and 85 throws an error!

   `0x800a138f - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: Die Eigenschaft "hitCanvas" eines undefinierten oder Nullverweises kann nicht abgerufen werden.`

Comment: Hi @user2561418, consider marking my answer as accepted if it has answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Taken straight from the KineticJS docs:

   > **`intersects(point)`**
   >   determines if point is in the shape, regardless if other shapes are on top of it. Note: because this method clears a temporary canvas and then redraws the shape, it performs very poorly if executed many times consecutively. Please use the [Kinetic.Stage#getIntersection](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getIntersection) method if at all possible because it performs much better

   With that being said, calling `intersects(pos)` every 100ms in a double **`for each`** loop for all your shapes is going to have a very heavy hit on performance `O(n^2)`. The slowness will increase exponentially with the more objects you have, hence 10 nodes is already slowing down your application!

   You're most definitely better off creating your own collision detection algorithm here to increase performance from collision detection, since it looks like you need to detect collision very often (in this example, every 100ms). Because you're detecting collision between dots (circles) I recommend looking into bounding circle collision algorithms. Check this site out for more info: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/12/12/GameDev-math-recipes-Collision-detection-using-bounding-circles.aspx
2. You're getting that error because the `intersects(pos)` method expects a point object in the form of `{x: newX, y: newY}`, what you are passing is wrong.

   This is wrong:
   `intersects(newX, newY)`

   This is right: `intersects({x:newX, y:newY})`